# is it possible to run another page via javascript from a page thats already been called via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

My issue is that i've opened a modal window using  that uses another page to gather data based on whats already clicked, e.g.

```
            <script>
            function showAcknowledge(str) {
                if (str.length == 0) { 
                    document.getElementById("txtAcknowledge").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                } else {
                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("txtAcknowledge").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                        }
                    };
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getacknowledge.asp?q=" + str, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
            }
            </script>
```

This opens the page to get data from the database and display a form.

```
            <script>
            $(document).on("click", ".accCallb", function () {
                var idsel = $(this).data('ids');
                $(".modal-body #idsel").val( idsel );
                showAcknowledge(idsel);
                $('#accCallb').modal('show');
            });
            </script>
```

This passes the ID from the button

```
            <a onclick="document.getElementById('accCallb').style.display='block'" data-toggle="modal" data-ids="'+idb+'" href="#accCallb" class="accCallb w3-col l1 m2 s2 w3-button w3-right w3-red w3-small fa fa-check" style="padding:5px;margin-right:5px;" title="Acknowledge"></a>

            <div id="accCallb" class="w3-modal">
                <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4 w3-animate-zoom w3-large" style="max-width:800px">
                    <span onclick="document.getElementById('accCallb').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-xlarge w3-hover-red w3-display-topright" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                    <div class="w3-section">
                        <span id="txtAcknowledge"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the form / page gets displayed in the "txtAcknowledge" span.

Now this all works fine and the data I require is all there.

What I then want to do is use autocomplete to call some options from the database using autocomplete.asp
I can do this fine outside of getacknowledge.asp and even have autocomplete.asp code working directly in the modal, but I can't figure out how to get it working from within the modal that already calls getacknowledge.asp

This is part of the autocomplete.asp page:

```
            <div class="w3-section">
                <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-margin-bottom autosc" type=text name=searchdata placeholder="Search Data...">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    //autocomplete
                    $(".autosc").autocomplete({
                        source: "autocomplete.asp",
                        minLength: 3
                    });             
                });
                </script>
            </div>
```

So basically i'm calling a page getacknowledge.asp which then calls autocomplete.asp.
Is it possible?
Am i going around the issue all wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking. (I am sure I am not the only one) How is the modal coded? How is the data placed in the modal?

Comment: I agree with the above comment, post your code and the problem you are having, with any stack traces, we have no idea what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry reading it again its not clear.

Comment: Hopefully my edit is a bit clearer? As I said I may be going around it all wrong but that was the only way I could think of doing it.

Comment: Yes. It is possible but I cant understand the question

Comment: The autocomplete.asp page won't work being called from the getacknowledge.asp page that is being called from the modal. It works standalone or with just the code in the getacknowledge.asp page but not being called by the getacknowledge.asp page.